# How to group item of array by time with step

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I have an array like this:

```
let arr = [
  {
    title: 'Some title',
    start: '09:30:59',
    end: '09:33:59',
  },
  {
    title: 'Some title',
    start: '09:33:59',
    end: '09:35:59',
  },
  {
    title: 'Some title',
    start: '09:35:59',
    end: '09:40:59',
  },
  {
    title: 'Some title',
    start: '09:30:59',
    end: '09:45:59',
  }
  ...
];
```

And I want to get array grouped by some step for example 10:

```
let result = [
  {
    start: '09:30:59',
    end: '09:40:59',
    arr: [
      {
        title: 'Some title',
        start: '09:30:59',
        end: '09:33:59',
      },
      {
        title: 'Some title',
        start: '09:33:59',
        end: '09:35:59',
      },
    ],
  }, 
  {
    start: '09:40:59',
    end: '09:50:59',
    arr: [
      {
        title: 'Some title',
        start: '09:35:59',
        end: '09:40:59',
      },
      {
        title: 'Some title',
        start: '09:30:59',
        end: '09:45:59',
      }
    ],
  },        
    ...
];
```

I tried do it:

```
let step = 10;
let diffMinutes = dayjs(arr[arr.length - 1].end).diff(arr[0].start, 'm') / step;
let newArr  = [];
let result = [];
for (let t = 0; t < diffMinutes; t++) {
  newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (dayjs(arr[i].start).isBetween(arr[0].start, dayjs(arr[0].start).add(step, 'm').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))) {
      newArr.push(state.events[i]);
    }
  }
  result.push(
    {
      ...
      arr: newArr
    }
  )
}
```

I added condition with `dayjs` that check if event start time enters a certain period of time.
I think it can be made easier than I did.
Result shout be array grouped by time with stem 10.
Sopouse that in else statment I should use last item of last array result.
But it work only for first iteration, how to do that in next I dot know.

Help me please.

Comment: It seems a similar problem to merging intervals (https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/). You may check it out, there's a solution tab there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem [example](https://codepen.io/Yushko/pen/xxwawKy)

```
let step = 5;
let diffMinutes = Math.round(
  dayjs(arr[arr.length - 1].end).diff(arr[0].start, "m") / step
);
let result = [];
let newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= diffMinutes; i++) {
  newArr = [];
  if (i === 0) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (
        moment(arr[j].start).isSame(arr[0].start) ||
        moment(arr[j].start).isSame(
          dayjs(arr[0].start).add(step, "m").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
        ) ||
        moment(arr[j].start).isBetween(
          arr[0].start,
          dayjs(arr[0].start).add(step, "m").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
        )
      ) {
        newArr.push(arr[j]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    let lastResult = result[result.length - 1];
    let lastEllArr = lastResult[lastResult.length - 1];

    console.log("i" + i, lastEllArr.start);
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (
        moment(arr[j].start).isSame(
          dayjs(lastEllArr.end).add(step, "m").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
        ) ||
        moment(arr[j].start).isBetween(
          lastEllArr.end,
          dayjs(lastEllArr.end).add(step, "m").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
        )
      ) {
        newArr.push(arr[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  if (newArr.length !== 0) {
    result.push(newArr);
  }
}
```

If anyone suggests improving the code I would appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

You could take the first four characters of the time and group by this value.

```js
let array = [{ title: 'Some title', start: '09:30:59', end: '09:33:59' }, { title: 'Some title', start: '09:33:59', end: '09:35:59' }, { title: 'Some title', start: '09:35:59', end: '09:40:59' }, { title: 'Some title', start: '09:30:59', end: '09:45:59' }],
    group = s => s.slice(0, 4),
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = group(o.start);
        r[key] = r[key] || { start: key + '0:00', array: [] };
        r[key].array.push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another solution could be to use time values as seconds with an interval of seconds. The result is grouped by the interval and `start` and `end` properties are calculated with the given interval.

```js
let array = [{ title: 'Some title', start: '09:30:59', end: '09:33:59' }, { title: 'Some title', start: '09:33:59', end: '09:35:59' }, { title: 'Some title', start: '09:35:59', end: '09:40:59' }, { title: 'Some title', start: '09:30:59', end: '09:45:59' }],
    seconds = time => time.split(':').reduce((a, b) => a * 60 + +b),
    //interval = 600,               // in seconds, here 10 minutes
    interval = seconds('00:10:00'), // or by taking the seconds from a time string
    group = time => Math.floor(seconds(time) / interval),
    getTime = seconds => [3600, 60, 1]
        .map(factor => {
            var v = Math.floor(seconds / factor);
            seconds %= factor;
            return v.toString().padStart(2, 0);
        })
        .join(':'),
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = group(o.start);
        r[key] = r[key] || { start: getTime(key * interval), end: getTime((key + 1) * interval - 1), array: [] };
        r[key].array.push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I understand that but how to group these  items in array by time interval

Comment: do you need to take *dayjs*? if so, you could check if two times have a smaller duration than your wanted interval. if not, or if not take a difference, you could get from all the total seconds ad check if the delta is in the wanted range.

Comment: yes I use dayjs for check enterence item in time period